# How to correctly use inet_pton rotine in Windows 10?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I'd noticed that `arpa/inet.h` lib is not available for Windows platform. Also read that `winsock2.h` implements an analog function `InetPton` to converts an IPv4 or IPv6 Internet network address. Then I tried to build some instructions like:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
   struct sockaddr_in sa;

   InetPton(AF_INET, "10.20.30.40", &(sa.sin_addr));
}
```

And get below compilation error:

```
undefined reference to `InetPton'
```

What I need to do/include to use this function on Windows (10)?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I encountered this issue recently, and figured an answer, that I hope to be useful for anyone who stumbles upon it.

First, you have to include the **ws2_32.lib** library in the link editor window (assuming you are using Visual Studio).

Then, you have to define **_WIN32_WINNT** (more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-170)) before making the includes.

It may look like this for Windows 10.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
```

When looking in the **<ws2tcpip.h>** header, you will find that you will not have access to certain functions if the **_WIN32_WINNT** value is not set properly, or set for an old Windows version.

I hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the ws2_32.lib library.  That contains the Winsock functions.

See the [MSDN page for `InetNtop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.